# What are methods to represent a bag from multiple instances it contains?

Tags: python, methods, mean

Imagine having a dataset with multiple classes and each class contains multiple instances. Let's assume class 1 contains 6 instances. One way to represent class 1 as a single vector is to take the average of the 6 instances and denote class 1 as one line. What other methods can be applied to reduce 6 instances to one for Class 1.

[image: example_df]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/30/e86379e75ee49c9db22b151bfbc06b99-full.png))</sub>

after taking average for class id:

[image: after]
<sub>(source: [imggmi.com](https://cdn1.imggmi.com/uploads/2019/10/30/ebf0bb806fc81727064c0ab8dc2de287-full.png))</sub>

What other methods would you recommend?

Comment: with pandas group by you can actually aggregate a lot of properties from min, max, mean, sum etc and even use different function for different columns which is better than an entire average for all same class_id's

Comment: But can min or max application capture the essence of multiple rows for one class. What if those are outliers ? Can you recommend a method that will meaningfully capture the essence of the class like taking mean captures the central tendency of the class. Imagine there are hundred class id's each one having multiple instances.